# In C++, using a loop to find the # of days on any given date?

Tags: c++, date, loops

And yes this is an assignment-- So please don't post solutions, but detailed pseudocodes are extremely helpful!

I already have a program in C++ that accepts a date from the user and will determine if it is a leap year or not.

Here is my leap year function so far (I do hope that this is the correct logic):

```
bool isLeapYear (int year){
    int leapYear = 0;

    //leapyear = 1 when true, = 0 when false
    if ((year%400 == 0) && (year%100 != 100)) {
        leapYear = 1;
        }
    else if (year%4 == 0) {
        leapYear = 1;
        }
    else {
        leapYear = 0;
        }



    if (leapYear == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }     
}
```

Here is a paraphrase of what I must do next:

> You MUST use a loop that adds months one at a time to an accumulated sum.
>   Don't use any hardcoded values 
>   Such as 152 for the first 5 months in a leap year

And to clarify, this is my first programming class and have been in this C++ class for just about a month now.
So it would be greatly appreciated if anyone could help me figure out how to do the loop statements to add the number of the months?
(IE: 12/31/2013 should be "365" in a non leap year, and "366" in a leap year).

I know this is wrong but this is what I have so far for a function "dayNumber" that simply return the number of days in the year to the main function (which is calling the dayNumber function):

```
int dayNumber (int day, int month, int year){
    //variable declarations
    int sumTotal = 0;


    for ( int loop = 1; loop < month; loop++) {
        sumTotal = (( month-1 ) * 31);
        sumTotal = sumTotal + day + 1;
        if ( (loop==4) || (loop=6) || (loop=9) ||
            (loop==11) ) {
            sumTotal = ( sumTotal - 1 );
        }
        else if ( isLeapYear(year) == 1 ) {
            sumTotal = (sumTotal - 2);
        }
        else  {
            sumTotal = (sumTotal - 3);
        }

    }


    return sumTotal;
}
```

I started to mess around with it to get to a proper value for days I knew but it kind of messed it up more, haha.

If anyone has any guidance on how to appropriately do a loop, I would be extremely greatful!:)

**EDIT:
Alright, I think I may have answered my own question.**

> int dayNumber (int day, int month, int year){
>      //variable declarations
>      int sumTotal = 0;
>
> for ( int loop = 1; loop < month; loop++) {
>          sumTotal = ( sumTotal + 31 );
>
> ```
>    if ( (loop==4) || (loop==6) || (loop==9) ||
>        (loop==11) ) {
>        sumTotal = ( sumTotal - 1 );
>    }
> ```
>
> }
>      if ((month !=2) && (month > 1)) {
>          if (isLeapYear(year) ==1) {
>              sumTotal = ( sumTotal - 2 );
>          }
>          else {
>              sumTotal = ( sumTotal - 3);
>          }
>      }
>
> else {
>          sumTotal = sumTotal;
>      }
>      sumTotal = sumTotal + day;
>
> return sumTotal;
>   }

I definitely need to work on my loops. 
I appreciate letting me know that my '=' should have been '=='!

I believe this is an appropriate code using a simple enough loop? 
I will test some more dates. I've only tested the few provided on the class site so far.

**I can't answer my own posts, I don't have enough reputation.**

Comment: Good starting point to fire up a debugger now, step through your program line by line, and watch how variables change.

Comment: year%100 will never == 100

Comment: your for loop loops month-1 times. you should start it from 0 if you want to loop "month" times

Comment: Ah yes, when I run the program all my values are correctly going into the different functions. I've been checking that religiously as I've been writing this!:) 

I don't get any errors when I run everything. Rather, some dates just aren't adding correctly.

Oops, hit enter prematurely Haha.

EDIT: Rather, when I enter 5/5/2015, it should be 125 days. But it is calculated as 129.

Comment: Your first two statements in the loop are problematic. In the loop, you should add the length of the months, and you should add the days after the loop. Furthermore, you lose the work from the previous iterations by saying `sumTotal = (( month-1 )*31);`, which should rather be something like `sumTotal = sumTotal + 31` (or, in short, `sumTotal += 31`).

Comment: `if ( (loop==4) || (loop=6) || (loop=9) || (loop==11) )` This isn't doing what you expect. You're missing some `=` signs.

Comment: I really don't even know how to approach calculating number of days when using months? I feel as though the concept is over my head right now. 
I have a hard time with loops since we brushed over them in a week and started right away with some pretty intense nested ones. 

If anyone could possibly help me figure out a good pseudocode? 
My first instinct would just be to define constant variables with the # of days in the month then add them. But that does not work well in a loop does it?

Comment: @Chnossos oh wow, thank you! Yeah, I've been sitting down and writing this for way too long. I think a break from my computer would be great for my brain function at this point, especially when I'm missing easy points like that. Thanks!

Comment: @Rhymoid yep I had sumTotal = sumTotal += 31 earlier. Then I started playing around with my code because it wasn't working properly. I ought to save more copies of previous work. Yikes.
I've been up nearly 24 hours now so it's just very hard to process coding stuff, especially for an online class.

Comment: Hint - you should have class Date, then you have something like  static int cDaysInMonth[] = {
    31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
    }; And check this link for a sample class Date implementation - http://www.glenmccl.com/004.htm#tag04.

Comment: Ah, thank you SChepurin! But we actually haven't learned that yet and are unable to use it in our programs, lest we sacrifice our grade. D: I think it's an unfortunate opinion to have but our professor absolutely does not want us to use anything we have not been taught yet. So I am only allowed the simplest of code, which I honestly feel narrows my options more than it helps me haha.

Comment: @Katlyn - Just choose wisely what you are allowed to. Don't reinvent the wheel and save your time.

Comment: @Katlyn Are you allowed to use enumerations or simple arrays ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Haha. If I include anything we have not learned I do not get a grade. So unfortunately I cannot use your code. :(
The limitations in this class are beyond frustrating. I know more than is provided in the book but am unable to use it. I don't like it myself haha

Comment: Nope, arrays are in the next chapter!
It's quite silly, honestly. Typical school system thought though...if you know more we must dumb you down to everyone elses' level! 
I'm confident I could easily figure this loop out given enough time, but I am just having conceptual difficulties with the restrictions provided. ._.

Comment: Aside: `if (leapYear == 1) return 1 else return 0;` might as well be `return leapYear`. Also `bool` is not `int`. Use `true` and `false`.

Comment: You might be able to get around the "no arrays" restriction by fitting an equation like [this library does](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#days_from_civil) in it's calculation of "number of days since 1970-01-01" (you wouldn't need to add the days in years part), although that probably falls afoul of the "Don't use any hardcoded values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that giving detailed pseudocode helps more than a solution, but I'm not that good of a teacher yet :/ Good luck with this answer, and get some sleep when you're done :)

---

I'm assuming that `dayNumber(8, 3, 1914)` is supposed to return the ISO day number of 1914, March 8th.

What you want to do is the following:

```
procedure dayNumber(theDay, theMonth, theYear):
    set answer to 1  // the first day of the year is day 1
    for every month 'thisMonth', up to and excluding theMonth:
        increment answer by the number of days in thisMonth
    increment answer by (theDay - 1)  // the first day of the month is monthday 1
    return answer
```

In the iteration statement (or 'loop body'), there are three cases:

1. February: if it's a leap year, increment `thisMonth` by 29, otherwise increment by 28.
2. Short months (April, June, September, November): increment by 30 days.
3. Otherwise, long months (January, March, May, July, August, October, December): increment by 31 days.

This translates to:

```
if (thisMonth == 2) {
    // February
    if (isLeapYear(theYear))
        thisMonth += 29;
    else
        thisMonth += 28;
} else if (thisMonth == 4 || thisMonth == 6 || thisMonth == 9 || thisMonth == 11) {
    // Short month
    thisMonth += 30;
} else {
    // Long month
    thisMonth += 31;
}
```

(Note: `X += Y` is, or should be, short for `X = X + Y`.)

The loop logic you use looks mostly correct to me, except for 1) off-by-one errors because you start with day 0, and 2) adding the monthday inside the loop rather than outside of it:

```
int dayNumber (int theDay, int theMonth, int theYear) {
    int result = 1;

    for (int thisMonth = 1; thisMonth < theMonth; thisMonth++) {
        /* ... see above ... */
    }

    return result + theDay - 1;
}
```

---

Now, about making the iteration statement prettier, there are basically two ways (and if your course hasn't yet covered them, I of course recommend against using them in an answer). One is using a `switch` statement, but I'm really not a fan of them, and it doesn't provide much benefit over the code I already gave. The other would be to use arrays:

```
int dayNumber (int theDay, int theMonth, int theYear) {
    int monthDays[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
                        , 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 }

    int result = 1;

    for (int thisMonth = 1; thisMonth < theMonth; thisMonth++) {
        if (thisMonth == 2 && isLeapYear(theYear))
            // Special case: February in a leap year.
            result += 29;
        else
            /* Take the month length from the array.
             * Because C++'s array indices begin at 0,
             * but our first month is month 1,
             * we have to subtract one from thisMonth.
             */
            result += monthDays[thisMonth - 1];
    }

    return result + theDay - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**I know an answer has been accepted, but it took me some time writing my own, let's see if it can adds some informations overall.**

---

Let's review this slowly.

First, your `isLeapYear()` function isn't completely right.

Without delving into the algorithm part, two or three things can be improved.

1. You're returning a `bool`, yet your return statements are returning `int`s. This isn't wrong in itself, but using the `true` and `false` keywords can improve the readability and consistency.
2. Instead of creating, assigning and returning a variable, you should instantly return your result.
3. Add spaces around your operators : `year%400` should become `year % 400`.

---

Now your code.

This condition :

```cpp
if ((year%400 == 0) && (year%100 != 100))
```

... especially this part :

```cpp
(year%100 != 100)
```

Isn't doing what you expect.

Overall, the algorithm is as follow :

> **if** year is not divisible by 4 **then** *common year*
>   **else if** year is not divisible by 100 **then** *leap year*
>   **else if** year is not divisible by 400 **then** *common year*
>   **else** *leap year*

Translating it in code:

```cpp
/**/ if (year % 4 != 0)
    return false;
else if (year % 100 != 0)
    return true;
else if (year % 400 != 0)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

Now let's simplify this a bit:

```cpp
/**/ if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)
    return true;
else if (year % 400 == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Again:

```cpp
if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

And finally, the whole **boolean expression** can be directly returned:

```cpp
return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0;
```

---

Now that your function is correct, let's try an algorithm to your `dayNumber` function :

If the date provided in parameters is considered correct, then the algorithm is quite simple :

- Start `sum` from `0`
- Loop from 1 to `month` excluded

  - If `month` is Frebruary then add 29 if `isLeapYear` returns `true`, else 28
  - If `month` is January, March, May, July, August, October or December add 31
  - Else add 30
- Add `day` to `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctime>
static int GetDaysInMonthOfTheDate(std::tm curDate)
{
    std::tm date = curDate;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 29; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        date.tm_mday = i;
        mktime(&date);

        if (date1->tm_mon != curDate.tm_mon)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i - 1;    
}
```